# Spring MVC Java Configuration

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi I am trying to use Spring MVC Java config and Content View resolver.

Files:-

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer#onStartup(javax.servlet
 * .ServletContext)
 */
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(SpringMvcConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    ctx.refresh();
    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.setAsyncSupported(false);
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sambhav.mvc.controller" })
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /*
     * @Bean public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
     * UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
     * resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/"); resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
     * resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class); return resolver; }
     */

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver getTilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        /*
         * tilesViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
         * tilesViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
         */
        tilesViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return tilesViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer getTilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/tiles.xml" });
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(
            ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .favorPathExtension(true); // default is true. just for clarity
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/*").addResourceLocations(
                "/WEB-INF/css/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/*").addResourceLocations(
                "/WEB-INF/js/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/*").addResourceLocations(
                "/WEB-INF/img/*");
    }

}
```

When trying to run the app, I don't the dispatcher servlet getting registered - no related info logs appear. Running in debug mode with break point in WebInitializer also indicates that its not getting called.

```
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969 in 68 ms
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 573 ms
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.8.2.RELEASE/7.0.35.B.RELEASE
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor D:\Installations\sts3.2\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\spring-mvc-config.xml
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:spring-mvc-config' did not find a matching property.
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Installations\sts3.2\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\manager
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Installations\sts3.2\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\ROOT
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 12, 2013 5:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 311 ms
```

This results in 404 at /  or any other path.

I am wondering what went wrong here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its old question. With newer Spring Boot, it is now far easier to configure any Spring application. Refer Spring Boot starter project here :-

[Spring Boot Blog](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Answer (score 0):

**Possible reasons**:

1. web.xml. I advice you to delete it at all and use servlet-api with version higher than 3.0.
2. Incorrect @RequestMapping in controllers. Show them, please.

And finally, here you can find good step-by-step guide for base Spring MVC app with java configuration:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/spring-mvc-creation-of-a-simple-controller-with-java-based-config.html